# Combobox selectedvalue and override ToString() - MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have a combobox which displays data from an override `ToString()`. I also have a datagrid text column that also gets its values from override `ToString()`.

What I want is to sync the combobox to the datagrid so that when we click on a datagird row it shows the same value in the combobox and when we change the value in a combobox it updates the datagrid cell.

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to do it with `ToString()`. It works when I bind it to a property with a getter and a setter. But I need it to be on `ToString()`.

Model

```
  public class SifKorisnici: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _ime;
        private string _prezime;

        public string Ime
        {
            get { return _ime; }
            set
            {
                _ime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Ime");
            }
        }

        public string Prezime
        {
            get { return _prezime; }
            set
            {
                _prezime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Prezime");
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Prezime + " " + Ime;
        }
    }
```

Datagrid

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListaOdjeli,Mode =TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="0,180,0,0"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Voditelj" Binding="{Binding SifKorisnici,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid>
```

Combobox

```
  <ComboBox Name="OdaberiKorisnika" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaKorisnikaCombo, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="120" 
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKorisnici,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItems.SifKorisnici??,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedValuePath="SifKorisnici??"

                  IsEnabled="{Binding JeOmogucenGumb}"
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: The property is already a string, what are you expecting different? Otherwise, put your special formatting into the property get.

Comment: I know its a string what I need is to bind that property to selectedvalue and selected value path so that when the user clicks on the datagrid the combobox displays the selected value and when we change the combobox value datagrid updates it